# Integrated Brownian motion $\int_{0}^{t} W_s \, ds$ properties

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

I have 2 questions on integrated Brownian motion and would appreciate any guidance on them.

**Question 1**

Let $\mathcal F_t = \sigma(W_t)$, the $\sigma$-field generated by $W_t$, is $$Z_t = \int_{0}^{t} W_s \,ds$$ $\mathcal F_t$-measurable? Why so?

I asked the above because I am trying to prove:

For $\mathcal F_t = \sigma(W_t)$ and $Z_t = \int^{t}_{0}\,e^{W_u}\,du$ show
$$E[Z_T|\mathcal F_t]=Z_t+W_t(T-t)\quad\forall \,t<T$$

The solution provided from the book I am using https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9620 is
\begin{align}
E[Z_T|\mathcal F_t] &= E\left[\int^{t}_{0}W_u\,du|\mathcal F_t\right] + E\left[\int^{T}_{t}W_u\,du|\mathcal F_t\right] \\
&= Z_t + E\left[\int^{T}_{t}W_u - W_t+W_t\,du|\mathcal F_t\right] \tag1 \\
&= \cdots
\end{align}

Wouldn't $(1)$ imply that $Z_t$ is $\mathcal F_t$-measurable? But I am not sure why.

**Question 2**

In an attempt to prove $cov(Z_t, W_t) = \frac{t^2}{2}$, consider

\begin{align}
cov(Z_t, W_t) &= E[Z_tW_t] - E[Z_t]E[W_t] \\
&= E[Z_tW_t] \\
&= E\left[W_t\int_{0}^{t}W_s\,ds\right]\tag1 \\ 
&=E\left[\int_{0}^{t}W_tW_s\,ds\right] \tag2 \\
&= \cdots 
\end{align}

What is the reason for $(1)$ to $(2)$? Does it have to do with Fubini's theorem? 
Gordan's answer in [Correlation between stochastic processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825671/correlation-between-stochastic-processes/1825843#1825843) may be helpful for context.

Thanks!

Comment: Question 1: Why would it be, unless you mean $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(\cup_{s\leq t} W_s)$?. Question 2: You can always push in constants into an integral. Here $W_t$ is a constant as it does not depend on the integration variable $s$.

Comment: @JasonGaitonde Thanks. However, with regards to question 1, please see the edition in the thread above, in particular showing $E[Z_T|\mathcal F_t]=Z_t+W_t(T-t)\quad\forall \,t<T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment for Question 1: $Z_t$ is not measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ as you have currently written it, as it depends on values of $W_s$ for all $s\leq t$, not just $W_t$. It is, however, measurable with respect to $\sigma(\cup_{s\leq t} W_s)$, that is, the sigma-algebra generated by all previous values of $W_s$. To understand why, note that the map $s\mapsto W_s$ is a.s. continuous, so the integral $Z_t$ exists and moreover is almost surely equal to the limit of Riemann sums. The Riemann sums for this integral are just linear combinations of $W_s$ for $s\leq t$, so each Riemann sum is measurable with respect to $\sigma(\cup_{s\leq t} W_s)$, and therefore the same is true of the limit.

Comment: I suppose it is a typo by the author then. I was suspicious about it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: Yes. According to Ito product rule $d(tW)=W dt+tdW$, then we could get
$$
\int_{0}^t W(s)ds=tW(t)-\int_{0}^{t}s dW(s)
$$
For the right-hand side of first term, it is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable;for the second term, it is also $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable.
For how to determine whether a random variable is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable, there is an sentence from Oksendal in his book named " Stochastic Differential Equations"  which may be helpful. It says,

> Intuitively, that $h$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable means that the value of $h(w)$ can be decided from the values of $B_s(w)$ for $s\leq t$. For example, $h_1(w)=B_{t/2}(w)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable, while $h_2(w)=B_{2t}(w)$ is not.

Question 2: since the integral $\int_{0}^t W_s ds$ is for variable $s$, therefore you could recognize $W_t$ as a constant. The integral has no influence on $W_t$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

What I understand from $\mathcal F_t$-measurability is a random variable X is  $\mathcal F_t$-measurable if $\{X \in (a,b)\} \in \mathcal F_t \, \forall a,b \in \mathbb R$. But I still do not see why by that definition, $Z_t$ is $\mathcal F_t$-measurable. 

Also, I have not learn Ito's product rule. Would you have another explanation then?

Comment: sorry about the answers for question1. I did not notice that part. I thought you forgot to write it. But anyway, you got your answer.

Comment: No worries! Thank you for your reply nevertheless